# Loss installing my tl-wn727n each update ubuntu

Tags: updates

I installed my tl-wn727N thanks to the site's explanations. Unfortunately, each update Ubuntu, I lose my wi-fi connection and I have to restart the installation. What should we do to avoid losing running my tl-wn727n each update

Comment: How did you install drivers?

Comment: sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential git
git clone https://github.com/porjo/mt7601.git
cd mt7601/src
sudo make
sudo make install
sudo mkdir -p /etc/Wireless/RT2870STA/
sudo cp RT2870STA.dat /etc/Wireless/RT2870STA/
sudo modprobe mt7601Usta

Answer (score 0):

You lose the kernel module not after each update, but only after a kernel update.

You do not need to download drivers and copy firmware each time. If you keep the source of the driver you can only run:

```
cd mt7601/src
sudo make install
```

Maybe you will need to start the module if it does not start automatically by

```
sudo modprobe mt7601Usta
```

This does not reqire an internet connection.

To make it fully automatical, you need to create a `dkms.conf` file and install the driver using DKMS. In this case the module will be automatically rebuilt after each kernel upgrade.

You can read about DKMS [HERE](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DKMS).